# From the $XY$ and $XZ$ graph, find the correlation between $X$, $Y$, and $Z$

Tags: correlation

[image]
[image]

The answer is $Z = \dfrac{X}{Y}$. Can someone explain it to me?

Answer (score 1):

The second chart suggest to me that it is possible that $Z=\frac XN$, where $N$ takes positive integer values.  It looks like a set of straight lines through $(0,0)$ where the right hand ends are, or are close to, $(1,1)$, $(1,\frac12)$, $(1,\frac13)$, etc.

But the first chart is really not good enough to even suggest $Y=N=\frac{X}{Z}$.  I cannot tell whether $Y$ only takes integer values, and more importantly, apart from a handful of points on the left, I cannot match $X$ values between the two charts to confirm the relationship. It even looks as if some $Y$ values are $0$ and may not correspond to points on the second chart at all (infinite $Z$?). So $Z=\frac XY$ is not obviously ruled out by these charts, but there is nothing visual to suggest it is true either.